# Unable to filter rows of one table based on data in another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables `tbl1` (552 rows) and `tbl2` (257 rows) with unequal rows in my PostgreSQL database (PG 9.5, x64 Windows). The tables tbl1 and tbl2 contain the following data (sample shown here):

```
Grp   id   val1   val2   sum
1     1    112    142    5.2
1     2    124    137    6.7
1     3    136    189    6.8
1     4    112    114    9.8
1     5    130    145    6.1
1     6    142    130    7.7

Grp  id    sum
1    1     5.2
1    3     6.8
1    6     7.7
```

For each group in table 1, I am trying to select rows where "id" in the first table is not equal to "id" of second table. For example, my expected output would be:

```
Grp   id    val1   val2   sum
1     2     124    137    6.7
1     4     112    114    9.8
1     5     130    145    6.1
```

I have tried this query so far but it doesn't work, and return empty output.

```
SELECT
   a.grp, a.id,
   a.val1, a.val2, a.sum
FROM tbl1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl2 b WHERE b.grp = a.grp AND b.id != a.id
)
```

Can someone help on this and explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change to `AND b.id = a.id`

Comment: Care to post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `NOT EXISTS` the condition you need is `b.id = a.id` and not `b.id != a.id`:

```
...................
WHERE b.grp = a.grp AND b.id = a.id
...................
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that the `NOT EXISTS` clause will always return false with the data you have shown in the sample (for each row in a, there is a row in b where grp is the same but id is different).

A `LEFT JOIN` with a `IS NULL` filter will do the trick:

```
SELECT a.grp, a.id,
    a.val1, a.val2, a.sum
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON a.grp = b.grp AND a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL --b.id is null if there is no row in b which matches both a.grp and a.id
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I tried but the trick with NULL didn't work, cheers!